# How to override class methods

Tags: ruby, overriding, class-method, prepend

I want to override the method `Selenium::WebDriver.for`. This is what I tried:

```
module SeleniumWebDriverExtension
  def self.for(browser, *args)
    if browser != :phantomjs
      super(browser, *args)
    else
      options = {
          "phantomjs.cli.args" => ["--ssl-protocol=tlsv1"]
      }
      capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.phantomjs(options)
      super(browser, desired_capabilities: capabilities)
    end
  end
end

Selenium::WebDriver.prepend(SeleniumWebDriverExtension)
```

But I got error when `Selenium::Webdriver.for(:phantomjs)` is called.

```
NoMethodError: super: no superclass method `for' for Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:Class
```

How can I call the original method from the overriding method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
module SeleniumWebDriverExtension
  def for(browser, *args)
    ...
  end
end

Selenium::WebDriver.singleton_class.prepend(SeleniumWebDriverExtension)
```

Comment: Clever, thanks! We now use this to amend `NewRelic::Agent::Hostname.get` with a fallback to super.

Answer (score 4):

When to you use `self` inside a module like this:

```
def self.for(browser, *args)

end
```

it is declared as a `module function`, not an instance method on the class that will include this module. What this means is that won't appear on included classes when the module is mixed into another class.

It is similar to writing:

```
 def SeleniumWebDriverExtension::for
 end
```

So if you want to call `super` from within the module, declare it as a simple `instance method` like the accepted answer has suggested. Just wanted to clear you on the reasoning behind this.

Btw `SeleniumWebDriverExtension.ancestors` to be clear on the inheritance hierarchy.